# Is it possible to use jquery getScript on a file that is cached with a cache.manifest

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, cache-manifest

I'm fetching a file using getScript:

```
    $.getScript("android/android.js")
```

and the I cache that file in a cache manifest:

/android/android.js

When i Try to load the page cached, I get a "Get" error.

Comment: Did you try the way described in the `jQuery.cachedScript` example on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be default, $.getScript() sets the cache setting to false. This appends a timestamped query parameter to the request URL to ensure that the browser downloads the script each time it is requested. You can override this feature by setting the cache property globally using $.ajaxSetup():

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: true
});
```

Alternatively, you could define a new method that uses the more flexible $.ajax() method.

From [jQuery's documentation on getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: Hmm... doesn't seem to be honoring the `cache: true` for me as it is still appending the query string to prevent caching. I'll try to figure out what's up.

Comment: Works for me :) Thanks!

Comment: WARNING: This will enable caching for every ajax call, not just your script call. Instead, replacing `$.getScript` with an `$.ajax` call is the way to go.